# Why f'{None}_some_string' not throw an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I wonder why `f'{None}_some_string'` not throw an error?

Here is some example to reproduce the problem:

```
s1 = None # <class 'NoneType'>
s2 = 'real_string' # <class 'str'>

s1 + s2 # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str


f'{s1}_bla'

'None_bla'

f'{s2}_bla'

'real_string_bla'
```

Is it possible to make expressions like `f'{s}_some_string'` throw an error when `s` is `None`?

Comment: No. F-strings automatically convert all the embedded expressions to strings. So it's analogous to `str(s1) + str(s2)`

Comment: Don't use an f-string if you don't want automatic formatting.

Comment: @Barmar Then the question is why `str(None)` not throw an error?

Comment: `str(None) ` is `'None'` it's valid

Comment: Because the `NoneType` class provides an `__str__()` method that returns the string `'None'`

Comment: @mrgloom Because `None.__str__()` is implemented and returns the string `'None'`

Comment: Why do you want it to throw an error within format?  If you want to raise an exception, check the value before creating the f-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default f-string apply the `str()` (string) function.

```
f'{None}_some_string'
```

is equivalent to...

```
f'{str(None)}_some_string}'
```